# Touch response with opengl android

Tags: android, opengl-es

I want to add a touch event in my android program that use openGL. as I'm new in android coding and openGL, I don't know which method should I use.

1. The method showed in android developer page,that use shaders.
2. Is a method that I googled and is like add points and attach the points in cw or ccw.

I draw points in 3D space by the second method and I want to use touch events to rotate those points. By animation I can do it, (rotatef) but I don't know how and where can I add the touch event.

problem Solved...